# Deleting rows, and rows that reference row ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say we have a table for drawings.

```
CREATE TABLE public.drawings
(
  drawingid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('drawings_drawingid_seq'::regclass),
  name text,
  discipline text,
  type text,
  CONSTRAINT drawings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (drawingid)
);
```

And we have a revision table that stores all the revision data of each drawing.

```
CREATE TABLE public.revisions
(
  revisionid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('revisions_revisionid_seq'::regclass),
  drawingid integer,
  sequence integer,
  revision text,
  state text,
  meta jsonb,
  "Description" text,
  "TB_DRAWING_NO" text,
  "File Name" text,
  "ATT_CADTYPE" text,
  "PW_SUITABILITY" text,
  "TB_TITLE_LINE_1" text,
  "TB_TITLE_LINE_2" text,
  "TB_TITLE_LINE_3" text,
  "TB_TITLE_LINE_4" text,
  --snip
  "RV_APPDATE10" timestamp without time zone,
  "RV_APPDATE11" timestamp without time zone,
  "RV_APPDATE12" timestamp without time zone,
  "File Updated" timestamp without time zone,
  "Updated" timestamp without time zone,
  "Created" timestamp without time zone,
  "File Updated By" text,
  "Updated By" text,
  "Created By" text,
  CONSTRAINT revisions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (revisionid),
  CONSTRAINT revisions_drawingid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (drawingid)
      REFERENCES public.drawings (drawingid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Say I want to delete a lot of rows from `drawings` table, but I also want the related revisions to be deleted from `revisions`, I don't want to leave orphaned rows. What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achive that, you can use the `CASCADE` keyword from PostgreSQL when defining your constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT revisions_drawingid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (drawingid)
    REFERENCES public.drawings (drawingid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Now, when deleting a row in `drawings`, it will automatically delete orphaned rows in `revisions`.

[Working SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1614f).